# xPath, getting all <p> tags inside a div

Tags: html

I'm trying to add my site to Instant view telegram. I'm attempting to access all the p tags inside a specific div. My xPath query looks like this, this should in theory return all p tags, however it only returns the first. Does anybody know how I might return all p tags?

```
body: //section[contains(@class,"ipsType_richText")]//p/*
```

Comment: weel the "body: "-part can't be part of a Xpath. Or dit you mean: 
//body//section[contains(@class,"ipsType_richText")]//p

Comment: the problem remains

Comment: Please show the html

Comment: <div class="ips_game_tg"> <section class="ipsType_richText ipsType_normal" data-controller='core.front.core.lightboxedImages'>
<p>
 content
</p>

<p>
 content
</p>

<p>
 content
</p>

<p>
  Content
</p>
</section></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Xpath:

```
//section[contains(@class,"ipsType_richText")]/p
```

wil select form this html:

```
<div class="ips_game_tg">
  <section class="ipsType_richText ipsType_normal" data-controller="core.front.core.lightboxedImages">
    <p> content </p>
    <p> content </p>
    <p> content </p>
    <p> Content </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

This 4 p

```
<p> content </p>
<p> content </p>
<p> content </p>
<p> Content </p>
```

If that does not work, something else is wrong.

Comment: Very strange. Still only selects the first p tag